# Why is WritableConverter private?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to have a function that opens a sequenceFile and provides the path of the file containing the K/V pair. I was thinking something like this:

```
def sequenceFileWithPath[K, V](
  input: String,
  minPartitions: Int
)(implicit
  sc: SparkContext,
  km: ClassTag[K],
  vm: ClassTag[V],
  kcf: () => WritableConverter[K],
  vcf: () => WritableConverter[V]
): RDD[(Path, K, V)] = {
  val rdd = sc.sequenceFile[K, V](input).asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[K, V]]
  rdd mapPartitionsWithInputSplit {
    case (inputSplit, t) =>
      val path = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit].getPath
      t map { case (k, v) => (path, k, v) }
  }
}
```

```

However, `WritableConverter` is private, making the compilation to fail. Questions:

1. Why is `WritableConverter` private? I have the feeling it makes it harder to extend the functionality of `sequenceFile[K,V]`. Also, the it would be useful to reuse the converters available.
2. How to get around this in order to still be able to have a function call using Scala types instead of instances of `Writable`, like `sequenceFileWithPath[String, Int]`?